# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python

I built a traffic light detection model, everything else works fine. but when I tried to display the prediction and the ground truth visually, it gives me an error like above. I guess the predict function is wrong somehow. is anybody can help?  below is the code.

```
# Display the predictions and the ground truth visually
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
   j = 1
   for i in range(0, 1000, 100):
       truth = test_labels_a[i]
       prediction = model.predict(i)
       plt.subplot(5, 2, j)
       j = j + 1
       plt.axis('off')
       color = 'green' if truth == prediction else 'red'
       plt.text(40, 10, "Truth:        {0}\nPrediction: {1}".format(truth, prediction),
                fontsize=12, color=color)
       plt.imshow(test_x[i], cmap='gray')
```

Comment: can you add the full traceback please?

Answer (score 0):

The `model.predict(i)` should probably be something like `model.predict(test_data)`